# Making video appear mid animation

Tags: animation, video, keyframes

I am currently working on an animation. Somewhere in the middle (say frame 200) of this animation, a video has to appear. I use the "import images as plane" plug-in from the user preferences to have video appear in the animation.

My problem is, that I don't know how to make the video appear in mid animation. I cannot add the video at the beginning and just unhide it in frame 200, since then it will already be halfway through.

Does anyone have a trick that can help me?

Best regards and Thank you!

Comment: Is the  video supposed to be on a tv? or is it a hologram?  is it supposed to be something in your scene?

Comment: It is a tv. the tv appears in front of a character at frame 200 and starts playing immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I used a material.  I had a screen material with two elements in it.  a black screen, and a emission with a movie texture on it.  I mixed them together and then animated the factor of the mix node to make it turn on.[image: heres a picture of my node setup]

please comment if you need more info,

hope this helps.